# [Dual system, Ubuntu 20.04]nvidia-gpu: i2c timeout error; ucsi_ccg: i2c_transfer failed -110, ucsi_ccg_init failed

Tags: boot, nvidia, 20.04, shutdown

I have been tortured by a *tiny* bug for a long time. Now I really hope to fix it.

They only shows when I boot/turn off my computer, although it doesn't influence anything.

- when I boot my pc, it usually shows:

```
/dev/nvme1n1p3: clean, **** files, **** blocks
[   5.004707] nvidia-gpu 0000:05:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   5.004734] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
[   5.004772] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
```

- when I turn off:

```
[   42.056815] ata2: failed stop FIS RX (-16)
[   43.065169] ata1: failed stop FIS RX (-16)
```

My configuration: Win 10 Pro + Ubuntu 20.04, RTX 2060s, amd r7-3700x.

I just don't want to see them everytime when I turn on/off my pc! Is there anyone know how to fix this?

Much appreciate:)

Comment: Btw, I remember I edited some configuration related to nvidia when installed ubuntu 20.04, but I can't remember them now. I don't have the integrated graphics with this PC.

Answer (score 23):

I also have this issue in my Windows 10 + Arch Linux. It seems to be a bug in nvidia driver, as discussed in [this link.](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206653) Some nvidia cards don't have USB Type-C interface, yet still try to load its `i2c` driver. Hopefully this problem will be fixed in the next version of the driver.

As far as I know, there are two solutions for this problem in the meantime:

1. You may try to patch your linux kernel, see the link above. If I understand correctly, the patch downgrades level of the error.
2. You may want to create a file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist_i2c-nvidia-gpu.conf` with these contents: `blacklist i2c_nvidia_gpu`. This file prevents loading the problematic driver.

Personally, I use method 2, since my card doesn't have USB-C interface.

Comment: How did you do method 2? I ran sudo nautilus and pasted the .conf file I saved to my desktop directory to the /etc/modprobe.d/ directory. But it didn't work.

Comment: @JulienShepherd do `su` and then `echo "blacklist i2c_nvidia_gpu" > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist_i2c-nvidia-gpu.conf`

Comment: Do not forget `sudo update-initramfs -u` after add blacklist_i2c-nvidia-gpu.conf or it does not work for rejecting the problematic driver module.