# crash report pops up after login - xubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, xfce, apport

I had a crash report everytime I login into xubuntu 20.04.1,

after performing apt update and reboot, everytime I login into xfce session I got error report,
/var/log/apport.log,

```
ERROR: apport (pid 5806) Sat Dec 26 21:48:05 2020: called for pid 4827, signal 6, core limit 0, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 5806) Sat Dec 26 21:48:05 2020: script: /usr/bin/lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings, interpreted by /usr/bin/python3.8 (command line "/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings")
ERROR: apport (pid 5806) Sat Dec 26 21:48:05 2020: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 5806) Sat Dec 26 21:48:06 2020: wrote report /var/crash/_usr_bin_lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings.0.crash
```

output of journalctl -p 3 -b,

```
kernel: nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
kernel: ucsi_ccg 0-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
kernel: ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
lightdm[1022]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
lightdm[1022]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
lightdm[1022]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
lightdm[1022]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
lightdm[1103]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
lightdm[1103]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
lightdm[1103]: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet5.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
lightdm[1103]: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
lightdm[1103]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
pulseaudio[1057]: Error opening PCM device front:0: No such file or directory
pulseaudio[1172]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

system info :

```
System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-58-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: Micro-Star model: B360 GAMING PLUS (MS-7B22) v: 2.0 serial: <filter> 
           UEFI: American Megatrends v: 2.C0 date: 10/14/2020 
CPU:       Topology: 8-Core model: Intel Core i7-9700KF bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Kaby Lake rev: D 
           L2 cache: 12.0 MiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 57600 
           Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 800/4900 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 3: 801 4: 800 
           5: 801 6: 800 7: 800 8: 800 
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA TU116 [GeForce GTX 1660] vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: nvidia v: 455.38 
           bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: nvidia unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1660/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 455.38 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel 
           v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU116 High Definition Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel 
           v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.1 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-58-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Ethernet I219-V vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k 
           port: efa0 bus ID: 00:1f.6 
           IF: eno1 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 1.24 TiB used: 225.39 GiB (17.8%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Kingston model: SV300S37A120G size: 111.79 GiB temp: 36 C 
           ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Seagate model: ST1000DM010-2EP102 size: 931.51 GiB temp: 40 C 
           ID-3: /dev/sdc vendor: Apacer model: AS340 240GB size: 223.57 GiB temp: 40 C 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 101.28 GiB used: 8.55 GiB (8.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda3 
           ID-2: /home size: 219.06 GiB used: 3.75 GiB (1.7%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdc1 
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 8.10 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda2 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 45.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 47 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A gpu: nvidia fan: 0% 
Info:      Processes: 226 Uptime: 1h 03m Memory: 15.58 GiB used: 1.57 GiB (10.1%) Init: systemd 
           runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38
```

notes: fresh install, iso from https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/20.04/release/

Edit :

output of `ls /var/crash/ -atl`:

```
total 15816
drwxrwsrwt  2 root   whoopsie    4096 Des 27 01:42 .
-rw-r-----  1 sapxml whoopsie   67144 Des 27 01:42 _usr_bin_blueman-tray.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 sapxml whoopsie 2972026 Des 27 01:41 _usr_bin_xfce4-power-manager.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 sapxml whoopsie 7713059 Des 27 01:17 _usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_tumbler-1_tumblerd.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root   whoopsie 5425695 Des 26 21:48 _usr_bin_lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings.0.crash
drwxr-xr-x 14 root   root        4096 Jul 31 23:35 ..
```

update :
I reinstall the xubuntu 20.04.1, and retracing some steps of what I did, during the update installation process of `sudo apt upgrade` I open the *lightdm GTK+ greeter* and it won't open and continue to reboot anyway, hence the next login pops crash report, after reinstall, I refrain doing anything until the update process is finished, reboot, then no crash report is present, though reinstalling pops another issue which redirect to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1871268 but somehow succesful in third attempts,

Comment: What is the output of `ls /var/crash/ -atl`?

Comment: output of     ls /var/crash/ -atl
'total 5308
-rw-r-----  1 root whoopsie 5425695 Des 26 21:48 _usr_bin_lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings.0.crash
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie    4096 Des 26 21:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root        4096 Jul 31 23:35 ..'

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: so sorry about that, was wondering through a lot "add comment" formatting and tried a lot and get hit with "5 minutes edit", it is now included in question, thanks

Comment: try to blacklist the faulty nvidia module https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278399/dual-system-ubuntu-20-04nvidia-gpu-i2c-timeout-error-ucsi-ccg-i2c-transfer