# Ubuntu 20.04 disables proprietary Nvidia GPU drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I've tried to keep my 20.04 installation Nvidia GPU-drivers 'fresh' for dev purposes. I have used the manual/local installation scripts from Nvidia, installation goes fine and the system works fine no problems. However, after couple of boots Ubuntu reverts GPU-drivers back to 'X.Org X server'. Is there a way/log to check why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: The log files may have a clue. I'd look at dmesg to start with.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @mikewhatever, seems the following answer relates to my dual setup and issue: https://askubuntu.com/a/1289997/1174588.

Comment: This happens after each kernel upgrade and it is expected. If you install drivers from repos or a PPA, this won't happen.