# Nvidia timeout error e0000000 on Dual System

Tags: drivers, dual-boot, nvidia, bios, boot-repair

Recently my Windows 10/Ubuntu system started creating this error when I boot Ubuntu (Windows is fine):

`nvidia-gpu: i2c timeout error e0000000 ucsi_ccg 0-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110 ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed -110`

I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278399/dual-system-ubuntu-20-04nvidia-gpu-i2c-timeout-error-ucsi-ccg-i2c-transfer) talking about the same error, but they described it as minimal, as not influencing their usage. For me, however, it boots in a very low screen resolution before running a bunch of processes and showing me in a full screen text window messages in the following format:

`[  OK  ] Started/Finished Process`

All of the processes start with that OK tag, here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnHl7.jpg).

After this, the whole screen goes black with a blinking text entry sort of symbol in the top corner, but I can't type or do anything. As far as I know, the Ubuntu partition of my system is completely inaccessible.

I am very new to Linux, but the text in the pic above looks to me like programs that are always started before the os is fully loaded: core parts of snap, date and time, disk manager etc all seem like necessary processes for the os.

This happened after I did two things:

First, I updated Ubuntu and restarted, then I tried to enable virtualization by enabling IOMMU in my bios settings. This is when this started happening, I tried undoing my changes to the BIOS and loading the base stable presets over whatever else may have changed, but the bug persisted.

Currently I am leaving this blank screen I described above to see if something happens after a while. I'll come back with an update on that if I see something.

Update: after pressing alt enter (or some sort of coincidental timeout) the system rebooted to windows on its own. And, since this is probably a graphics card issue, my card is the GTX 1660, the same which triggered the bug report linked by the older question. I'm reading through that bug report to see if there is anything more I can do.

Update 2: My system is working but the bug persists. I won't have the time to fix it in the near future but I'll do my best to put aside some more time to parse through the linked question above. I think I'll turn off IOMMU just to be safe since the thing I needed it for is also no longer within the bounds of what I have time to deal with.

Comment: What sort of bootloader/boot manager are you using to manage the dual boot process? There's a high likelihood that breaking out of the boot failure cycle for your Ubuntu installation is going to require the manipulation of your kernel command line arguments, the access to which is dictated by the loader or manager in use. If you already know how to do so, could you attempt to add `nomodeset` at the end of the kernel command line and report any changes to the boot process? You could also try `recovery`, also as the last argument in the kernel command line. Best of luck to you.

Comment: It's honestly kind of scuffed...
I DONT have a boot manager, at least I haven't installed one externally. I just press f12 on startup and select the linux boot and press enter.
If I don't do anything it boots straight to windows lmao

I'll look into getting a boot manager working with the windows side of things

Comment: Ok, here's the issue with the boot manager: Windows doesn't recognize Ubuntu as an operating system. In "Startup and Recovery" it just lists Windows 10 in the os menu, probably because the Ubuntu drive is in FAT32 format

Comment: Good news! I booted into Grub. Idk where to go from there though

Comment: I don't know what I did, I don't want to know what I did, but my computer is turning on now, even though the bug is still happening. That was enough of an emotional rollercoaster for me today so I'm going to check back in tomorrow to try some of the techniques from the older post

Comment: @Pablo Ibarz all of your comments adding info need to be placed in the question via edit not as comments. Comments are where someone trying to help you asks for more info.