# i2c error nvidia-gpu

Tags: nvidia, i2c

I installed new kernel

```
uname -r
6.0.0-1007-oem
```

And after this I get error on booting and nvidia-driver (nvidia-driver-525-open)
doesnt work

```
Dec  7 21:38:57 pc kernel: [    8.169416] nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
Dec  7 21:38:57 pc kernel

nvidia-smi 
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.: [    8.169436] ucsi_ccg 1-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
```

I have nvdia 1660 Super

Thanks

Comment: Nvidia drivers don't yet work with that kernel.

Comment: Does this solution work for you https://askubuntu.com/a/1289997/1198244

Comment: Same problem: [    8.677918] nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[    8.677921] ucsi_ccg 3-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
[    8.677927] ucsi_ccg 3-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110  seems to me to be something about USB-C devices, maybe try unplugging any USBC devices you have plugged in?  Just guesses at this stage.  I have a GTX1660 and MSI motherboard.